# OOP design - Decentralizing methods in seperate files

Tags: php

I have two files: `config.php` and `init.php`.

`config.php` has a `config` class with configurations for various server setups. `init.php` has the `init` class with all the methods for business logic.

`init extends config`

I use the ezsql library for MySQL interfacing. I call it as a variable in init (`$init->sql`). So far so good.

My `init.php` has grown to be a huge file with numerous methods. Some pages use it just for calling ezsql. I want to move all the methods related to certain area of the site in their respective files and include those files only when I need them.

How do I implement this in actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you class is too large, it probably has too many responsibilities. See the **[SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)**.
You should probably restructure your application.

Comment: Any ideas over how I should proceed with the restructuring?

Comment: Well, you need to identify the entities in your application, and structure your classes appropriately. Since you know your app the best, only you can do it. You can post a question here on StackOverflow, describing your application and asking how to structure it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the autoload tool. There is a `spl_autoload_register` function that allows you to create rules to autoload classes.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php